# How to silently install MySql server in Installsheild?

Tags: c#, mysql, winforms, installshield, silent-installer

i want to install Mysql server in client mechine during installation of my Actual Application using IntallShield Limited Edition i have already tried an approach that just place the MySQL.msi in an exe and run the exe in installshield during installation of my Application but it throws an error that is "Another installation is in Progress.You must complete that installation before continuing this one".I think this error comes bcz Windows Installer is busy to install my Actual application and it doesn't Install more than one App simultaneously. So how can i install MySQL parallel to my App?Thanks

Comment: One approach would be to create a small bootstrapper that runs your installer, then MySQL's installer (or vice versa), then reboots just once if necessary. However, I question whether installing MySQL on the "client machine" is necessary? Usually, MySQL is installed just once on a server machine, then client applications connect to it. Or, if your application truly does need MySQL, that's often left up to the end user to configure (so they can use their preferred version for management, etc).

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but our Application is portable just like plug and play no need to configure any thing from client side bcz this App is available publicly in future and every one is not a technical person so that they can install Sql or other configuration  stuff.Well can u plz explain Bootstrapper and how to use or any reference for further details.

Comment: In that case, you might want to consider an embedded database like SQLite, which doesn't require server software to be installed.

Comment: A "bootstrapper" (probably the wrong name actually, this is just a setup script) is an executable script that installs the two MSIs using `msiexec`. You may wish to use the `/quiet` option for MySQL to hide its installation UI from the user. If you only want the user to have to download one file, this script would also have to go and download the MSIs from your website when the user runs it.

Answer (score 0):

> > i want to install Mysql server in client mechine during installation of my Actual Application using IntallShield Limited Edition i have already tried an approach that just place the MySQL.msi in an exe and run the exe in installshield during installation of my Application but it throws an error that is "Another installation is in Progress.

I would suggest you to create installshield prerequisite for Mysql server, and include this prerequisite in your application, so that the prerequisite will be installed before your application.